# Analysis of non-linear non-linear ODE and the form of curve on sphere

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

My questions is connected to a curve which appears on sphere: a point moves on a meridian which is rotating with constant speed while the point is moving along the desired curve with uniform acceleration on the sphere.

So, I am trying to understand the possible solutions of the non-linear equation
$(at)^2 = R^2(|\dot \theta|^2 + \omega^2 \sin^2 \theta)$, where $a>0$, $R>0$ and $\omega>0$.
Due to
$\frac{(ds)^2}{(dt)^2} = |v(t)|^2 = R^2(|\dot \theta|^2 + w^2 \sin^2 \theta)$
and
$\dot s = at$

In case of small $\theta$ we get $(at)^2 = R^2(|\dot \theta|^2 + \omega^2 \theta^2)$ and it is possible to find the solution (see [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A202407)).

However, I am not sure what to do for large $t$ or/and for the large $a$, i.e.
$t \to \infty$ or $a \to \infty$ and what is form of such a curve on sphere?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Your phrasing is confusing. What do you mean by "with uniform acceleration on the sphere"? Are you referring only to the tangential component of the acceleration?

Comment: @ Ted Shifrin Like https://oeis.org/A202407 but the curve is on sphere, $d^2s/dt^2=a$ and $s'=at$ on sphere.